# How to transfer elements of numeric value in Array in vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

If I enter any numeric value its digits should settled in array for any length of numeric value.

How to transfer it into array as mentioned below , without doing it manually because numeric value length can be vary it is not fixed.

```
 n = 454512
'*****how no should store in array***********
    a(0) = 4
    a(1) =5
    a(2) =4
    a(3) = 5
    a(4) = 1
    a(5) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the number to a string of digits; (Re)Dim the array wrt length of string; use Mid() to get the digits. In code:

```
>> n = 454512
>> s = CStr(n)
>> l = Len(s)
>> ReDim a(l - 1)
>> For p = 1 To l
>>     a(p - 1) = CInt(Mid(s, p, 1))
>> Next
>> WScript.Echo TypeName(a(0)), Join(a, "*")
>>
Integer 4*5*4*5*1*2
>>
```